# css not applying style to range of nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

i have following Markup, I am trying to get elements colored dynamically to the range I define, what's happening is that the style is dynamically calculated but it is applied for the 1st set of calculation that I make, following is my markup

```
<div class="container scrollme">
    <div class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
        <div class="table-row table-header table-light">
            <div class="table-row-column table-row-index">Cohort</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center"># of New Users</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">0</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">1</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">2</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">3</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">4</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">5</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">6</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">7</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">8</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">9</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">10</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">11</div>
            <div class="table-row-column table-center">Total Closed</div>
        </div>
        @foreach($output as $table_row)
            <div class="table-row">
                @php
                    $counter=0;
                    $index_non_zero = null;
                @endphp
                @foreach($table_row as $key => $value)
                    @if($value != 0 and $key < (count($table_row)-1))
                        @php
                            $index_non_zero=$key;
                        @endphp
                    @endif
                    @if($value != 0 and $key == (count($table_row)-1))
                        <style>
                            .table-row-column:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+{{$index_non_zero+1}}) {
                                background-color: purple;
                            }
                        </style>
                    @endif
                    <div class="table-row-column table-center">{{$value}}</div>
                    @php
                        $counter++;
                    @endphp
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update your example to remove the programming code and give us an example of what you're actually rendering? HTML/CSS/etc.

Comment: It may have something to do with the placement of your <style> tag midway down the page. If you need to change a style based on some value it might be easier to just assign a class to each element that needs it. eg. <div class="table-row-column bg-purple">...</div>